# How to select two fields in to one filed

Tags: php, mysql

i have mysql table:

```
id | nameEng | NameRus
1  | Moscow  | Москва
2  | London  | Лондон
```

What i want is:

```
$result = array (
  1 => array (id => 1, Name => "Москва"),
  2 => array (id => 1, Name => "Moscow"),
  3 => array (id => 2, Name => "London"),
  4 => array (id => 2, Name => "Лондон")
)
```

Here is my query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT id, nameRus FROM citynames WHERE nameRus LIKE '%".$_GET['chars']."%' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, nameEng FROM citynames WHERE nameEng LIKE '%".$_GET['chars']."%' ORDER BY nameEng LIMIT 0, 10"
```

Query working but i want to optimize this query

Comment: `2 => array (id => 1, Name => "Москва")`, and all the strings in `"..."`

Comment: i wanna optimize query @Ruben Kazumov

Comment: I totally understood your passion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$l = "like '%". $_GET['chars'] ."%'";
$sql = "(select `id` as `id`, `nameEng` as `name` from `citynames `) union (select `id` as `id`, `NameRus` as `name` from `citynames `) where `name` $l order by `id`;";
```